# How can redirect output of SQL query to a text file using Python

Tags: python, pyodbc

Redirect SQL query output to a text file using Python and pyodbc module.

```
import pyodbc
import os
import sys
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=win-intrst-srv;'
                      'Database=Interests_db;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
count1 = cursor.execute("select count(*) from MissedEvents  where  TenantId > 10000 and remarks like 'Mandatory%' AND RowCreatedDate >= dateadd(hh, -2, getdate())")
print(count1.fetchone()[0]) # This prints out no of rows updated in last 1 hour.

f = open('c:\MonitoringStats\staticentry.txt','a')
f.write('\n' + 'Mandatory field missing count:'+ count1.fetchone()[0])
file.close()
```

But it's failing with the error:

> Type error: Nonetype object is not subscriptable

Can someone help me in redirecting the SQL query output to a file?

Comment: It seems likely that your query only returns one row.  Therefore, calling fetchone() twice could be the problem.

Comment: Since you are only retrieving a single (scalar) value, just use `row_count = count1.fetchval()` and you'll have an `int` variable named `row_count` that you can print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already fetch your result when you print it, you cannot fetch that same result again.
So you should assign it to a variable :

```
count = count1.fetchone()[0]
```

Then use it as you want:

```
print(count)
...
f.write('\n' + 'Mandatory field missing count:'+ str(count))
```

Comment: pyodbc's `.fetchval()` is a handy alternative to `.fetchone()[0]`.